# ActiveRecord & Postgresql: Query jsonb attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have a model `Characteristic`, with a `equivalent` attribute which is a jsonb value.

ex:

```
characteristic1: 
id:1
equivalent: {list: ['first', 'second', 'third']}

characteristic2: 
id:2
equivalent: {list: ['fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']}
```

How can I find the record with `second` in the list using active record query interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way:

```
Characteristic.where("equivalent -> 'list' ? 'second' ")
```